php.ini not updating under Ubuntu with Plesk
My php.ini file updated the first time, but won't update anymore.
I have an IONOS cloud server running PHP 8.2.2 under Plesk. The php.ini file is at /opt/plesk/php/8.2/etc/php.ini. I went into nano and changed open_basedir to the following.
open_basedir = /var/www/vhosts/skipbinz.com.au/uploads

I restarted Apache and PHP-FPM and php.ini shows the change had taken effect. Then, I realised the correct path should have been /var/www/vhosts/skipbinz.com.au/httpdocs/uploads. I made the change.
open_base_dir = /var/www/vhosts/skipbinz.com.au/httpdocs/uploads

Then I saved the php.ini file and restarted Apache and PHP-FPM. This time, the changes have not taken effect. It feels like only my first change took effect. Any subsequent changes are being ignored.
Note, when I reload the file in nano, the changes are there. But it doesn't show up in phpinfo();
In phpinfo() it shows the following for Core > open_basedir.
/var/www/vhosts/skipbinz.com.au/:/tmp/

I'm unclear why it would show /var/www/vhosts/skipbinz.com.au when that's not the path I entered. My path original had /uploads at the end, and then /httpdocs/uploads. I've even tried resetting php.ini back to open_basedir but this doesn't have any effect either.
It's like the php.ini file is updating, but phpinfo() is getting the old settings from somewhere else. I am relatively new to cloud servers so still a little confused as to how things work and I don't know where to look to see if something is overriding the settings.
Any ideas what might be preventing the changes taking effect would be greatly appreciated.
